# Closed Form Generating Function for sum of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I need to find a Closed Form Generating Function for a sequence whose $n$-th term is the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, i.e:

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}x^n$$

and am having difficulties. I am trying to approach it through differentiation since I could not find a way to do it recursively but I am not sure which apporach is right.

Comment: Note that $n!$ is not the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers. The right formula for that is $n(n+1)/2,$ which might make your task easier...

Comment: Edited it now will try to work it out thanks!

Comment: I think here starting with the geometric series and doing the second derivative would be a good start, to get the $n(n-1)$ in front of a power, Then it may have to be adjusted to shift things to line up with the right power, and perhaps something also adjusted so the first few terms end up right.

Comment: Differentiation is a good idea. What is the second derivative of $x^{n+1}$?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have it figured out.

The answer is : $$f(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^3}$$

We get this by starting with $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + ...$, taking the second derivative yields $2 + 6x + 12x^2 + ... = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$ then multiplying by $x\over2$ gives the desired series.